# Enable/disable GPS and toggle the icon in the status bar - android

Tags: android, gps, statusbar

I am trying to enable/disable the GPS in my android code :

```
final Intent broadcast = new Intent();
broadcast.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider");
broadcast.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
broadcast.setData(Uri.parse("3"));
context.sendBroadcast(broadcast);

Intent intent=new Intent("android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE");
if(isOn) intent.putExtra("enabled", true);
else intent.putExtra("disabled", false);
context.sendBroadcast(intent);
```

The GPS is enabled/disabled but the GPS icon in the status bar is not updating.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, these script-kiddie hacks have not worked in quite some time. You are welcome to lead the user to the Settings screen where they can enable or disable GPS, by means of starting [an `ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS` activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS).

Comment: First off, let me state that I know the issue of the OP. Calling this a script kiddie hack is quite on the offensive side, the intent is for a tasking application in which when some conditions are met, some actions are invoked, one of them might be 'Turn on my GPS'. also - GPS seems to turn on and off, but the button display isn't updated. directing the user to the configuration isn't a relevant solution here. if you have any other constructive insights that would be great.

Comment: Why is it a hack? It is the same as enable/disable wifi or bluetooth. Is it?

Comment: @Ron.B.I: "Calling this a script kiddie hack is quite on the offensive side" -- what else would you call hacking into the Settings app this way? "directing the user to the configuration isn't a relevant solution here" -- and so the app cannot offer this feature. Life goes on. In the absence of users being able to enable/disable individual permissions (e.g., `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`), Google decided for Android 1.5+, based on concerns over privacy, to block SDK apps from enabling (or disabling) any location provider. If you don't like that, build a ROM mod that allows it.

Comment: @user2534949: SDK developers cannot enable or disable Bluetooth either. I haven't poked around to see whether WiFi can be enabled or disabled, though I suspect the answer is that they can until perhaps Android 4.2.